# Вывод двух строк из одной таблицы в одну строку

Tags: sql, база-данных, join, ssms

В базе данных есть таблицы, которые связаны следующим образом(см. рисунок)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно создать представление, которое будет выводить данные о предприятиях: название, вид собственности, адрес, менеджер, гл. энергетик.

Проблема заключается в выводе последних двух. То есть нужно вывести в одну таблицу для каждого предприятия ФИО и телефон менеджера, ФИО и телефон главного энергетика, а эти данные находятся в одной таблице(Employees)

Как написать такой запрос на SQL?

Comment: На таблицу предприятий заджойнить сначала манагера, затем шева или наоборот

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос для вывода данных может выглядеть так:

```
select e.name company_name
     , e.address company_addres
     , e.ownershipform company_form
     , em.name manager_name
     , em.surname manager_f
     , ec.name chief_name
     , ec.surname chief_f
from enterprises e
join managers m on on e.manager = m.id
join employess em on m.manager = em.id 
join cpes c on e.chiefpowerengineer = c.id
join employess ec on c.cpe = ec.id
```

где: алиас em это данные менеджера, а алиас ec это данные шефа.

> ##### ВАЖНО!
>
> **Если шеф или менеджер могут отсутствовать в таблице enterprises, то *JOIN* надо заменить на *LEFT JOIN*, иначе записей не будет вообще представлено в выборке**

Вам надо перестать думать о таблицах, как о единой и не делимой сущности. Одну и ту же таблицу можно представлять в запросах многократно.

Comment: Запрос выводит одинаковые значения имён и фамилий двух сотрудников.

Comment: @AlexandrTsvetkov Поправил запрос